# Master page permission problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, custom-masterpage

I have a single master page and say i have 3 users like 2 admins and the other is normal user.now in the master i need different links for different users.like the links available for first admin shouls not be there for the second and normal user should  not have any links.
For this i have tried
1.Security Trimmed control(working fine but for one Admin)
2.List permission(have used content editor webpart its working fine for sitepage but when i use it in the master page i have problem in Targeted audience setting even though i have specified targeted audience it is visible to all users)

How to fix this issue...Please share  your ideas ASAP

Answer (score 1):

Audinces can help you: [MSDN: Manage audiences](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263065%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
If you point web-part to specific audience, it will be shown only for its members.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not the best solution but, why don't you try to create different permission levels and create sharepoint groups just for those users and assign those SharePoint groups to the permissiones levels?.

Then, you would create a WebPart embbeded in the master page that reads from the list with the links and in the .cs you control the custom gruous permission.

Sorry but I cannot imagine a better solution yet